# Issue in saving Xgboost model in spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, machine-learning, xgboost, apache-spark-ml

I trained a xgboost model in spark scala as follows:

```
val xgbParamGrid = new ParamGridBuilder()
  .addGrid(xgb.maxDepth, Array(5, 10))
  .addGrid(xgb.maxBins, Array(2))
  .addGrid(xgb.minChildWeight, Array(0.2))
  .addGrid(xgb.eta, Array(0.015))
  .addGrid(xgb.alpha, Array(0.8, 0.9))
  .addGrid(xgb.lambda, Array(0.9, 1.0))
  .build()

// Create the XGBoost pipeline
val pipeline = new Pipeline().setStages(Array(xgb))

val evaluator = new MulticlassClassificationEvaluator()
  .setLabelCol("label")
  .setPredictionCol("prediction")
  .setMetricName("accuracy")

val cv = new CrossValidator()
  .setEstimator(pipeline)
  .setEvaluator(evaluator)
  .setEstimatorParamMaps(xgbParamGrid)
  .setNumFolds(3)

val xgbModel = cv.fit(trainingData)

val xgbBest = xgbModel.bestModel.asInstanceOf[PipelineModel].stages(0).asInstanceOf[XGBoostClassificationModel]
```

Then I tried to save it to local as:

```
xgbBest.write.overwrite.save(modelSavePath)
```

but got error message as:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
>           at scala.runtime.BoxesRunTime.unboxToLong(BoxesRunTime.java:105)
>           at org.apache.spark.ml.param.LongParam.jsonEncode(params.scala:480)
>           at ml.dmlc.xgboost4j.scala.spark.params.DefaultXGBoostParamsWriter$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$3.apply(DefaultXGBoostParamsWriter.scala:73)
>           at ml.dmlc.xgboost4j.scala.spark.params.DefaultXGBoostParamsWriter$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$3.apply(DefaultXGBoostParamsWriter.scala:71)
>           at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
>           at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
>           at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
>           at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
>           at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
>           at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:104)
>           at ml.dmlc.xgboost4j.scala.spark.params.DefaultXGBoostParamsWriter$$anonfun$1.apply(DefaultXGBoostParamsWriter.scala:71)
>           at ml.dmlc.xgboost4j.scala.spark.params.DefaultXGBoostParamsWriter$$anonfun$1.apply(DefaultXGBoostParamsWriter.scala:69)
>           at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
>           at ml.dmlc.xgboost4j.scala.spark.params.DefaultXGBoostParamsWriter$.getMetadataToSave(DefaultXGBoostParamsWriter.scala:69)
>           at ml.dmlc.xgboost4j.scala.spark.params.DefaultXGBoostParamsWriter$.saveMetadata(DefaultXGBoostParamsWriter.scala:51)
>           at ml.dmlc.xgboost4j.scala.spark.XGBoostClassificationModel$XGBoostClassificationModelWriter.saveImpl(XGBoostClassifier.scala:480)
>           at org.apache.spark.ml.util.MLWriter.save(ReadWrite.scala:103)
>           at classificationWithXgboost$.main(classificationWithXgboost.scala:125)
>           at classificationWithXgboost.main(classificationWithXgboost.scala)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:894)
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:198)
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:228)
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:137)
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)

Can anyone help with the problem? Thanks

Comment: How do you integrate xgboost with spark? With the XGBoost4j-Spark package (https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/jvm/xgboost4j_spark_tutorial.html)?

Comment: what xgboost version do you use?

Comment: I am using xgboost 0.81_snapshot. Cmake and maven build from local. Then include .m2 maven repo in build.sbt